# Can I @extend complicated class in SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have this auto-generated scss file that is beyond my control and I can't change it.

```
[class^="auto-generated-class-"]:before,
[class*=" auto-generated-class-"]:before {
  ... styling properties...
}
```

I want to `@extend` this class into another class

```
.my-new-class {
  @extend [class^="auto-generated-class-"]:before
}
```

and get as a result

```
.my-new-class {
  ... styling properties ...
}
```

this `@extend` doesn't work and I get an error message. Sass is looking for a simple `@extend` like `@extend .simple-class` and there is no documentation for a complex extend like `@extend [class^="auto-generated-class-"]:before`. Is there a way to make a complex `@extend` like that?

Comment: It's not "obvious" why this doesn't work, because we don't know what results you're expecting.

Comment: @cimmanon I've edited the question to be more specific. I couldn't find any duplication - can you provide a link to something that may appear similiar to that question?

Comment: The question this is a duplicate of is linked at the top ^.